# CSS - Stack list item below each other

Tags: html, css

Supposed I have a growing list:

```
<ul>
  <li>#1</li>
  <li>#2</li>
  <li>#3</li>
  ......
</ul>
```

And I want to make it to look like a stack, meaning the former ones will be above the latter ones. For example:

[image]

I guess I may have to make each list item float to left, shift it with something like `left: -5px;`, and decrease the z-index, but since there might be indefinite numbers of items, I am not sure how to achieve it for all items with CSS.

Thanks

Comment: maybe with something like this : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: As you may have an infinite number of items, translation by a fixed amount (-5px) might not work too well. You could try out a sigmoid-type function which shifts less and less, eventually saturating to some reasonable value (say, -50px) as item count goes to infinity.

Comment: @Dinesh wouldn't the translation amount have to increase since they items are being added to the right?

Comment: @JosanIracheta you are right, thanks for pointing out. I had meant only the relative translations should decay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Float won't work. Here are two approaches for the first you need absolute (or at least relative) positions, according position parameters and z-indexes:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid #fa0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
  background: #fff;
}

li:nth-child(1) {
  z-index: 3;
  left: 20px;
}

li:nth-child(2) {
  z-index: 2;
  left: 120px;
}

li:nth-child(3) {
  z-index: 1;
  left: 220px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>#1</li>
  <li>#2</li>
  <li>#3</li>
</ul>
```

ADDITION / SECOND SOLUTION:

If you can live with the elements being stacked the other way round (see snippet below), here's a pure CSS solution where you don't need sepearate settings for each element. THe only extra thing you need here is a `div` inside each of the `li` elements:

EDIT / ONE ADDITIONAL CHANGE:

To achive a layering like in the image that's included in the question, I reversed the order in the HTML and applied `direction: rtl;` to the `ul` element:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 40px;
}
li {
 display: inline-block;
  width: 110px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: visible;
}
li > div {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  border: 3px solid #fa0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><div>#3</div></li>
  <li><div>#2</div></li>
  <li><div>#1</div></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do you make this work for indefinite numbers of list items instead of hard code a few with z-index? Say there could be 30 items in this list, or 300...

Comment: Please note that I added a second solution that doesn't require separate CSS settings for each element.

Comment: I did another edit: To achive a layering like in the image that's included in the question (left one on top), I reversed the order in the HTML and applied `direction: rtl;` to the `ul` element:

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work, though it stacks in the opposite way.

Vistually stacking it the other way requires some more magic. You can achieve it (somewhat) by using `float: right;` instead of `float: left;`. Your UL will require some width and/or positioning tweaks then. And it visually orders the LI-items in reverse, which you could counter by generating your list sorted 'backwards' in HTML. If you want, I can help a bit more with that.

```css
ul {
    display: inline-block
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -20px;
    float: right;
    background: red;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>#3</li>
  <li>#2</li>
  <li>#1</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes the key is how to stack it the other way around... can you please share some code sample/thoughts on how to achieve that?

Comment: I've updated my answer, the HTML-list is now sorted 'backwards', and it's floated to the right. This also means the list is aligned to the right. To counter this, I added `display: inline-block` to the UL style.

Answer (score 0):

**I think this is a good example:**

https://codepen.io/bdpavel/pen/MEJOKz

**CSS**

```
ul {
    display: flex;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

li {
    display: flex;    
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: -40px;
    border: 3px solid orange;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: white;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

ul li:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think it's stacked the other way, is it possible to reverse the stacking order - like the sample image in the question?

Comment: @AllanJiang - I'm not the answerer, but you can flip the order easily like [this example with `flex-direction: row-reverse;`](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jGyYmO).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using a little help from js.

```js
var lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');
var i = 1;
for (var li of lis) {
  li.style.left = i * 50 + "px";
  li.style.zIndex = lis.length - i;
  i++;
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type:none;
  position:relative;
}

ul li {
  border:4px solid blue;
  border-radius:50%;
  display:inline-block;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position:absolute;
  background-color:white;
  text-align:right;
  line-height:5em;
  padding:8px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>#1</li>
  <li>#2</li>
  <li>#3</li>
</ul>
```